# Limit 1 of each from different column if conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

Is there a way to say, select 2 rows from the database, where one column equals something, or one column equals something else, but you want one row each from EACH equal conditions? So...

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName = '1' OR colName = '2' LIMIT...
```

1 where colName = '1', and 1 where colName = '2'. So, one of each.

Comment: `SELECT FROM` you didn't select anything.

Comment: what do you mean *huh?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html - `SELECT * FROM`? `SELECT col FROM`? select "what"? anyway, see Gordon's answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh, yeah. Fixed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the values, then use `union all`:

```
(select t.*
 from tablename t
 where colname = '1'
 limit 1)
union all
(select t.*
 from tablename t
 where colname = '2'
 limit 1)
```